# Counter for graphs in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, graph

Im working on a code in the userform in the vba. For this, i have to plot a graph multiple times with the data i aquired online. But the graph ploted many times should be the same. So how do i call the first graph to fill the next one that is in another subrotine? I should use a counter right? How do i reuse the graph in other subroutine?

Comment: There are a number of methods available. You can use a counter, you can name them, you can delete them all and build them from scratch each time. If you post the code you have so far and some additional relevant information people will typically help you reach your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can accomplish this. The one I would suggest is to create a Graph and access it again and again to plot your data. You can use function like

```
Worksheets("SheetName").ChartObjects("Chart Name").Activate
```

Then you can use various other functions to change the source data of the activated chart multiple time in the loop.

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Data Range")
```

Here are links to the functions :  [ChartObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.chartobjects)